# Adding a Wordpress Build to a Nuxt Project

Tags: wordpress, nuxt.js

Does anyone know how to take an existing Wordpress build and install it in a subdirectory of a Nuxt project?

I had this previously on my just html based site so that the WP blog would show up at /blog, and I want to do the same.

I have a folder "blog" that contains the Wordpress files.

Answer (score 0):

**For Wordpress**

Being the bain of my existence - as far as I remember, you can move the default installation (normally in root), into a folder. All files, etc, and it should still work.

**For Nuxt**

You can technically deploy your Nuxt project to the root, and have a wordpress site live in that sub-folder.

**Configuration**

Lastly, you would need to ensure the Nuxt routing allows passthrough to that folder.

*Possible Caveat*

The main issue I can think of may be with the deploy for the Nuxt project, and ensuring that any custom folders on the "server" stays intact for deploy.